# Sum of time durations in Excel with decimal seconds

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duration

I have some time duration values in the form of hh:mm:ss.sssssss (for example 00:00:00.0806494 is 0.08 seconds and 00:09:47.8602830 is 9 minutes and 47.7 seconds). These are not times of the day but rather time duration meaning that the hours field is not limited to between 0 and 24 hours. I would like to sum up several of these fields in Excel to determine how long all of the steps combined take. However, Excel does not seem to recognize that this is a duration rather than a time of day. Additionally, the SUM function always seems to return 0, or performs the sum as if it is a time of day. I could convert all of these times to just seconds manually to have them just be a number and them sum them up but having Excel do this automatically would greatly save time for me.

Of additional note, in-case it changes anything, the sum is being performed across multiple sheets. So like the sum of Sheet1 A1, Sheet2 A2, Sheet3 A3 etc.

Comment: It is probably just a formatting issue, since both are stored exactly the same. To prevent the "rollover", format your cell to show duration. i.e:   `[hh]:mm:ss.000`  If that doesn't work, provide a proper example of your issue, as I cannot duplicate your problem from what you have posted.

Comment: Also, if you enter the value ` 00:09:47.8602830` in an excel cell, Excel will see it as 9 minutes and 47.860 seconds.  If that is not what you want, you will have to do some mathematical conversions using formulas to accomplish that conversion.

Comment: If it is not a formatting issue, it might be that your values are stored as text (you can check that using the `=ISTEXT()` function which should be false). Be aware that if you use European settings in Excel, you might need to use comma `,`, like in `00:00:00,0806494`.